# Telnet test is OK, but my java socket client is not working

Tags: java, sockets, character-encoding, telnet

My partner system services socket server. They don't share the client module, only test sample data.
First, I tested using telnet program and it's successful.
[this image link is the test using telnet program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WMES.jpg).
But my Java socket client can't receive message from socket server.
[this image link is result of my socket program.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2VJU.jpg)
Would you help me?
Thanks.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("file.encoding: " + System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
    try {
        Socket socket;

        final String HOST = "xx.xx.xx.xxx"; // partner test server
        final int PORT = 8994;

        try {
            socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(">>>");
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            System.out.println(">>>");
            throw ioe;
        }
        System.out.println("sending data:");
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        byte[] b = "xxxx52017082410332310000000020321                                    ONL00000                                                                                                              080081COP0045             3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/jOsBUe5I11C2mtP0j5tPSww==20170824103323                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ".getBytes();
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            os.write(b[i]);
        }
        os.flush();
        socket.shutdownOutput();
        System.out.println(new String(b) + "[END]");
        System.out.println("receiving data");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);

        }
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: "isnt working" isnt a working problem description. You are like a guy calling his garage "my car making strange noises. now tell me how to fix". not possible.

Comment: "But my Java socket client is not working." we'll need more detail. **What exactly** is not working? How did you try to solve it? Where in the code is it?

Comment: And take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GhostCat - the solution to "my car is making strange noises" is to spell cat correctly :-).  Schrodinger's cat: thinking inside the box since 1935 :-)

Comment: Sorry experts!! I am not good at using stackoverflow. So I edit my question and added image link. Thanks.

Comment: Dont link to screen shots. "telnet" is for sure putting up **text**. So please include anything that is text as formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

The sever socket program sent byte data, not string line.
Please find below my source code.

Thanks everyone.

```
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        System.out.println("SEND DATA[" +msg.length() + "] [" + msg + "]");
        oout = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        iin = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        oout.write(msg.getBytes());
        oout.flush();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1156];
        System.out.println("RECV DATA");
        iin.read(buffer);

        System.out.println("RECV DATA [" + new String(buffer) +"]");
```